# Determining the order of matrices in $SL(2, \Bbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, complex-numbers

## Problem

Determine the order of the matrices:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(60°) & -\sin(60°) \\
    \sin(60°) & \cos(60°) \\
    \end{bmatrix} 
\space B= \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\sqrt 2°) & -\sin(\sqrt 2°) \\
    \sin(\sqrt 2°) & \cos(\sqrt 2°) \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
in the group  $SL(2, \Bbb R)$.

## What I Have

It was easy for me to find $ord(A)$, because we know $ord(A) = n$ where $A^n = e$. In this case, we know $e$ is the identity matrix, so I just kept increasing the power of $A$ until I got the identity matrix. So $ord(A) = 6$.

## Where I'm Stuck

Finding $ord(B)$ is not as easy. I believe it has something to do with the fact that the matrix $B$ corresponds to the complex number $\cos(\sqrt 2°) + i\sin(\sqrt 2°).$

Comment: It might help to think of these as rotation matrices; can an integer multiple of $\sqrt2$ be an integer multiple of $360$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the assignment has been completed, my professor has posted the solution (which was alluded to in the comments). In case anyone else stumbles upon this question in the future, here you go.

Since the matrix B represents or corresponds to (but not equals to) the complex number $cis(\sqrt 2°)$, we are looking for the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $(B)^n = I$. In other words:

$$B^n= {\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\sqrt 2°) & -\sin(\sqrt 2°) \\
    \sin(\sqrt 2°) & \cos(\sqrt 2°) \\
    \end{bmatrix}}^n =
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(n\sqrt 2°) & -\sin(n\sqrt 2°) \\
    \sin(n\sqrt 2°) & \cos(n\sqrt 2°) \\
    \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} = I$$

This means we are looking for  $n \sqrt 2 = 360$, which is clearly impossible because
$\sqrt 2$ is irrational. So there is no $n$ that meets our requirements. We could say that $ord(B) = \infty$.